# How do I customize my WordPress shortlink structure in link-template.php without a plugin?

Tags: plugins, permalinks, links

Right now my shortlink structure looks something like this:

example.com/?p=451

I would prefer it to look more like this:

example.com/abc123

Any ideas how I can alter the code to do just this?

Comment: Do you mean edit the core file itself?  If so, that's probably not a good idea as it makes upgrading harder.  A plugin would be the way to go.

Comment: @Christopher Davis  This is true...Ahhh I was trying to avoid a plugin as many seem to slow down my sites.

Comment: Plugins don't slow down sites. Overly complex plugins that try to do too much slow down sites. I run upwards of 50 plugins and have no issues. Just something to keep in mind: simple is better.

Comment: How will you create this structure easily at the time of placing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so, as mentioned in my comment to you: altering core files is not a good idea.  But here is a plugin solution.

First we're going to create our own rewrite rules that rewrite `s/123` (replace 123 with a post ID) to `index.php?short=123`.  We'll also have to filter the WordPress query variables so we can use them later.

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26869_add_rewrites' );
function wpse26869_add_rewrites()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( '^s/(\d+)$', 'index.php?short=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26869_query_vars', 10, 1 );
function wpse26869_query_vars( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = 'short';
    return $vars;
}
```

The `add_rewrite_rule` call says "rewite s followed by a slash and a string of one or more digits to `index.php?short=the_string_of_digits`.

Then we can hook into template redirect and see if our query variable is there. If it is, we'll try and get a permalink out of it.  If that fails, we'll throw a 404 error.  Otherwise, we'll use `wp_redirect' to send folks to the actual post.

```
<?php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse26869_shortlink_redirect' );
function wpse26869_shortlink_redirect()
{
    // bail if this isn't a short link
    if( ! get_query_var( 'short' ) ) return;
    global $wp_query;

    $id = absint( get_query_var( 'short' ) );
    if( ! $id )
    {
        $wp_query->is_404 = true;
        return;
    }

    $link = get_permalink( $id );
    if( ! $link )
    {
        $wp_query->is_404 = true;
        return;
    }

    wp_redirect( esc_url( $link ), 301 );
    exit();
}
```

Finally, we hook into `get_shortlink` to change how our rel="shortlink" appears in the `<head>` section of the site, and elsewhere.  This new shortlink structure will reflect the rewrite rule we wrote above.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'get_shortlink', 'wpse26869_get_shortlink', 10, 3 );
function wpse26869_get_shortlink( $link, $id, $context )
{
    if( 'query' == $context && is_single() )
    {
        $id = get_queried_object_id();
    }
    return home_url( 's/' . $id );
}
```

As a plugin:
https://gist.github.com/1179555

Comment: I'm actually having a little bit of trouble with this plugin. Right now my ShortUrl (without any plugin or modification to WordPress) looks like this structure: example.com/?p=451  How can I get it to look like this: example.com/short451 (I guess 451 is the post id?)

Comment: You need to change your permalink settings to pretty permalinks.  `settings > permalinks`

Comment: do I need to somehow activate this option? I don't see it in settings > permalinks

Comment: Nope, just select something other than default for your permalink structure and it should work.

Comment: @ChristopherDavis How many redirects happen here? 1 or 2? I mean, **(1)** from `http://example.com/s/121` to `http://example.com/?p=121` to the `actual permalink`? or **(2)** from `http://example.com/s/121` directly to `actual permalink`?

Comment: One redirect happens.  `example.com/s/121` is rewritten, not redirected.  The function hooked into `template_redirect` actually does the redirect from short URL to the canonical permalink.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from @ChristopherDavis's answer, you can also do it in a PHP independent way, using .htaccess. Simply add this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^s/(\d+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Alternative without `mod_rewrite`, using [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html):

```
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/s/(\d+)$ /?p=$1
```

The only problem is, two redirects happen here (instead of 1) — (for example) if user visits `http://example.com/s/121/` he is redirected by the web server to `http://example.com/index.php?p=121/` and then by WordPress to the actual permalink of the post.

The advantage is, this never breaks! Plugins may break, but this does not.

**PS:** [I use this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11281990/1071413) (short link structure would be `http://example.com/-121` where 121 is post ID):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^-(\d+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

using [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin, you can add a redirect which achieves this without touching PHP or .htaccess.

**prerequisites**

- install and set up Redirection plugin

**add redirect**

- go to Tools > Redirection
- click **add new** button

**redirect parameters**

- source url: **^/s/(\d+)$**
- url options (*located far right*): **choose regex**
- target url: **/index.php?p=$1**

---

**this method has the following advantages**

- no PHP coding, no .htaccess editing
- access tracking - you can see how many are hitting the shortlink redirect right from the dashboard
- 404 logging - helps with troubleshooting in case you mess up the regex
- flexibility - if you want, you could create multiple shortlink redirects based on post type or source (e.g. email vs. print vs. media vs. youtube) for tracking purposes
- you can optionally make any rule case-insensitive - *this is especially useful if you are counting on people to enter this URL manually*

**notes**

thanks to @its_me for the .htaccess method as this gave me the exact regex expressions i needed